# OpenVPN allows some users to jump to other hosts in the LAN

Tags: centos, routing, openvpn, tun

All users can connect to host where OpenVPN runs but some users can jump to other hosts in the LAN. For example, *foo* user can reach host `10.2.0.1/32` (where OpenVPN runs) and hosts at `10.0.0.0/24` but *bar* user can reach only the host `10.2.0.1/32`.

For both users, the route table is the same

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    302    0        0 wlan0
10.1.0.0        10.2.0.5        255.255.255.128 UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.2.0.1        10.2.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.2.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

For generating the client's key I run

```
cd /usr/share/easy-rsa/2.0
source vars
./build-key --batch foo
```

The `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` file has

```
; server
mode       server
port       1194
proto      udp
dev        tun
keepalive  10 120


; networking
server     10.2.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig   10.2.0.1 255.255.255.0
push       "route 10.1.0.0 255.255.255.128"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
```

The server is a CentOS 7 (x86_64) running OpenVPN 2.3.11 and Easy RSA 2.2.2.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why can some users connect and others not?

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with your vpn configuration. Also no route to `10.0.0.0/24 ` is in the routing table. So the hosts must be somehow reachable via the default gateway. Maybe `traceroute` or `ip route get <target>` helps.

Comment: I just discovered this issue appears when tun0's IP is greater that 10.2.0.28/30. I think I should configure manually the IP assignment in CCD (Client Configuration Directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad: the issue was a post-routing rule in IPTables, it was

`-A POSTROUTING -s 10.2.0.0/27 -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE`

And it should be

`-A POSTROUTING -s 10.2.0.0/24 -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE`